# Fail to install 'react-navigation' getting GIT not available error

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I want to use `react-navigation` as mentioned on several tutorials and official documents to use react navigation you have to install it using yarn or NPM.
I tried both and getting same error.

YARN

```
>yarn add react-navigation
yarn add v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find the binary git".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\projects\\ReduxDemo\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

NPM

```
>yarn add react-navigation
yarn add v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Couldn't find the binary git".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\projects\\ReduxDemo\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

D:\projects\ReduxDemo>npm install --save react-navigation
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  react-navigation/react-native-tab-view resetting remote C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-9747c439 because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-9747c439: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-9747c439: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  react-navigation/react-native-tab-view resetting remote C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-0c5c085d because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-0c5c085d: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-0c5c085d: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  react-navigation/react-native-tab-view resetting remote C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-b354594d because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:14:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:69:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:81:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:90:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-b354594d: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:react-navigation/react-native-tab-view.git C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-react-navigation-react-native-tab-view-git-b354594d: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-navigation"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\projects\ReduxDemo\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: _**i would suggest a dirty way**_, go to your `package.json` and add `"react-navigation": "^1.4.0",` inside `dependencies` and try to run `npm i`

Comment: dirty way not working! ;)

Comment: seriously I'm not aware of the error log hint like this `npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git` , rofl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I solved it by installing "Git" you can get it here: [Git Download](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

While installing it there will be a option in the install instruction you should check. It something like add git to cmd or path. After that you should try installing the navigation package again. It worked for me but i dont know if its gonna work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have **git** *installed previously*, *and should be available in* `path`

You can check it using `git --version`.

Till then you can *directly reference* the *package* `yarn add react-navigation@1.5.1` for a specific version

Answer (score 0):

i have also the same problem it have conflict with other version of libraries you used in your project i was using react-native-image-picker.so it gives error.
so when in install the below version then it works fine.

```
npm install --save react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.27
```

this solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed GIT, Goto the dir you want to run, then right click on git bash here and then run the command. 
It worked for me!